# Не сходится размерность тестовой выборки при обучении логистической регрессии: куда теряется одна фича?

Tags: python, numpy, машинное-обучение, sklearn, shape

Работаю с набором mnist, пытаясь предсказывать цифры. Реализую модель PCA, которая выбирает признаки, чтобы отличать одну цифру от другой. Затем эти признаки отдаю в регрессию и пытаюсь предсказывать. И вот здесь траблы с тестовой выборкой. Ее размерность оказывается ниже на единицу в сравнении с обучающим фреймом. В итоге на финальной стадии код дает ошибку

> ValueError: X has 783 features per sample; expecting 784

При этом аналогичная обработка обучающего фрейма обеспечивает количество фичей на уровне 784 штуки.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

train = np.loadtxt('/kaggle/input/digit-recognizer/train.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
test = np.loadtxt('/kaggle/input/digit-recognizer/test.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)

train_label = train[:, 0]  # В нулевом столбце представлены конкретные цифры
test_label = test[:, 0]

train_img = np.resize(train[:, 1:], (train.shape[0], 28, 28))
test_img = np.resize(test[:, 1:], (test.shape[0], 28, 28))

scaler = StandardScaler()
train_img = scaler.fit_transform(train[:, 1:])
test_img = scaler.fit_transform(test[:, 1:])


pca = PCA(.95)
pca.fit(train_img)
pca.fit(test_img)

logisticRegr = LogisticRegression(solver = 'liblinear')
logisticRegr.fit(train_img, train_label)

print(test_img.shape)
print(train_img.shape)
# Размерность тестовой выборки (28000, 783)
# Размерность обучающей выборки (42000, 784)

# Код ниже предсказывает одно наблюдение
logisticRegr.predict(test_img[0].reshape(1,-1))
# вот здесь и возникает ошибка
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что в тестовом наборе в первом столбце стоит цифра??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по [описанию данных на Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/data?select=test.csv), в тестовой выборке отсутствует целевая переменная - `label`. Вам ее придется найти в рамках конкурса ;)